# Which Ports are open by Default on iPad 2 (iOS 6)?

Tags: ipad, ios, network

I have a Question:

Which Ports should be open on iPad 2 by default?

Because on a port scan, my iPad shows some completely irrelevant ports open (ex. IIS on port 1027)!

Comment: I don't expect any ports to be open as there are no services running on a non-jailbroken iPad?

Comment: It is not jailbroken.... All Apple iOS Devices have an iTunes Sync Port Open though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ports are open by default on iOS 6. This shouldn't be confused with the also true statement that iOS 6 will open network connections to several Apple servers so that APNS and iCloud push email and software updates work.

You will have to configure things like WiFi sync or run file sharing software or a web server to get the device listening on IPv4 ports.

I use an app called [Netstat](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8) from the iTunes Store to inspect all network connections. That should help you determine which setting or app has opened port 1027 on your device. On all my iOS 5 and iOS 6 devices, the only default open port (LISTENING) is on localhost/loopback.